# Modification of TDengine table structure

Tags: database

I am researching the design principles of TDengine data table and super table. Regarding the modification of the table structure supported by TDengine, if the table structure of the corresponding super table of 100 million tables is modified, the drop dick operation should be triggered when the modification is made because the version number of the recently changed structure is stored in a temporary array. How does TDengine face huge system pressure when dealing with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The action of alter stable indeed can result in certain level of performance degradation. The better way of avoiding such problem is to better arrange your data model, or give two/three more reserved fields in case of future use.